# URL slash encoding not being carried through

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, url, urlencode

I have some django/javascript/jQuery code that looks like this:

```
{% url 'motor.core.reports.views.view' 'CDSEM' 'Gallery' as report_url %}
var $item = $(this);
var $row = $item.closest('tr');
var $cols = $row.children('td');
var tool_name = $.trim($cols.eq(2).text());
var tool_id = $('#tools option:contains('+tool_name+')').val();
var date_time = encodeURIComponent($.trim($cols.eq(3).text()) + ' to ' + $.trim($cols.eq(4).text()));
var href = "{{ report_url }}?recipe={{ filters.0.value }}&lot={{ filters.1.value }}&date_time=" + date_time + '&tool_ids=' + tool_id + '&meas_checkbox=Meas&pr_checkbox=PR&ga_checkbox=GA&submit_preview=Generate+Report';
window.open(href, '_blank');
```

The date_time field is being properly encoded:

```
> date_time
< "02%2F05%2F2012%2012%3A12%3A21%20am%20to%2002%2F05%2F2012%2012%3A23%3A04%20am"
```

But when the browser gets the URL it seems to have been partially decoded (the slashes have been converted from %2F back to a slash):

```
http://127.0.0.1/report/CDSEM/Gallery/?recipe=&lot=&date_time=02/05/2012%2012:12:21%20am%20to%2002/05/2012%2012:23:04%20am&tool_ids=22&meas_checkbox=Meas&pr_checkbox=PR&ga_checkbox=GA&submit_preview=Generate+Report
```

And the date_time parameter is not being properly processed by my app.

How can I preserve the slash encoding all the way through back to my app?

Comment: Are you sure it is not processed correctly in the backend? Some browsers (Firefox...) display some encoded characters as if they are decoded, but it will send the encoded data to the web server.

Comment: I will check that, but if I manually change the URL to have %2F instead of the slashes it works.

Comment: It was my bug and had nothing do to with the %2F vs. slashes.